# How do I find and alter the Views field markup in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, theming

Below is a twig template: *core/modules/views/templates/views-view-unformatted.html.twig*:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a view of unformatted rows.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
 * - rows: A list of the view's row items.
 *   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
 *   - content: The row's content.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  <div{{ row.attributes }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I alter the markup (and add some php logic) in `row.content`? - which outputs markup such as:

```
<div class="views-field views-field-body">
  <div class="field-content">
    <p>Hello world!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Presumably, there is another twig template for this markup? I cannot find it. I have the twig [debugger](https://www.drupal.org/node/1906392) turned on, but there are no notes above the markup that renders each content field.

I've looked at the template preprocess functions in *views.theme.inc* too - can't see any markup being generated in those things.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`theme_views_view_field()` is one of the 17 currently remaining theme functions in Drupal 8. This is a special case that is both a theme function and a template, like `theme_field()` and `field.tpl.php` in Drupal 7. The fact that there is a still a theme function and that's where the output comes from by default is why you aren't seeing it in the `twig_debug` output, which only shows output from template files. The issue to fully convert `theme_views_view_field()` to a template is https://www.drupal.org/node/2348729.

Answer (score 2):

First, [enable twig debugging in sites/default/services.yml](https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374).

Then that should print a wrapper around each template that tells you which template it is exactly using for that piece of marking. In this case, it is probably views-field.html.twig or so.

Twig also reports what kind of suggestions you can use (e.g. a node type specific template for node.html.twig), but that doesn't work for views because views uses a different approach for that, and twig debug doesn't understand that yet.

Comment: I've got the debugger on. Getting the template suggestions too. But, it does not tell me anything for that particular piece of markup. I've searched for the string '<div class="views-field' in all D8 code, but can't work out where it comes from.

Comment: I voted this suggestion up as all suggestions are printed in the html source. The answer should be views-view-fields plus all suggestions but agree with @24ma13wg ... running into bug https://www.drupal.org/node/2118743 as not all suggestions are listed. I use Drupal 8.0.5

Comment: I added the Devel Kint `kint($hook);` in Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php ~ line 136 first line within its render() method  which at least shows all suggestions.